# browser can not download file but curl command can

Tags: curl

I’m trying to download a android NDK bundle file from this [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r20b-darwin-x86_64.zip) in my chrome browser.but it download slowly(about 14KB/s.see the pic1).when i download it in terminal use curl command.it download fast(about 5MB/s.see the pic2).i guess if the curl works OSI layer is different from browser?i'm so confusion.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFvMT.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdESY.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your second picture we cannot actually see at which speed it was downloading. In my machine both are downloading in basically the same speed. Maybe there was something else limiting the download speed of your browser, [some browser extension maybe](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2723955?hl=en)? You should check the task manager (activity monitor on mac) to see it there was something else consuming your bandwith.

As far as network protocols is concerned (since you implied it in your question when you mentioned the OSI layers), there is no reason for one to download faster than the other since they both do basically the same thing. They make an HTTP request for a file and then download the file using a TCP/IP connection. The main difference lies in the request headers defined by each tool. Below is the request made by my firefox to dowload the file (I couldn't get the request headers using the chrome dev tools’ network tab):

```
GET https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r20b-darwin-x86_64.zip
Host: dl.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: cookie_info...
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
TE: Trailers
```

And bellow is the request made by my curl

```
GET /android/repository/android-ndk-r20b-darwin-x86_64.zip HTTP/2
Host: dl.google.com
user-agent: curl/7.68.0
accept: */*
```

This is not enough to justify a difference in download speed.